# "Come" vs "come on"-"The bus should come on in at any minute."Is it idiomatic to use "come" to talk about something that's going to happen?

Tags: usage

I know I can say

[The streetlights come on automatically at dusk.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/come-on)

Now suppose that you and your friend have been waiting for a bus for a while.

And you turn and say

> The bus should come on at any minute.

Is that a proper usage for the phrasal verb "come on"?

My intention behind using "come on" instead of simple come is that I think using "come one" implies there is kind of schedule for the buss departure. I am not sure though.

Comment: **on** refers there to the active state. There is no implication of anything to do with time or schedules. *The lights come on when you clap your hands.*

Answer (score 2):

Your first example refers to the following usage:

***[come on](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/come-on_2):***

> to begin to operate:
>
> - Set the oven to come on at six.
> - When does the heating come on?

(OLD)

As for the bus I think you should use *[arrive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/arrive)* or come:

> The bus  should *arrive/come/be here* any minute.